# "PVOID" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCTSTR"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create a file on an `FTDI` chip so that I can write and output data. I get from the manual that to create a file the following line of code needs to be written:

```
ftHandleFile = FT_W32_CreateFile((PVOID)LocId, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
```

However, I get the following errors

> Error 1   error C2664: 'FT_HANDLE
> FT_W32_CreateFile(LPCTSTR,DWORD,DWORD,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,DWORD,DWORD,HANDLE)'
> : cannot convert argument 1 from 'PVOID' to
> 'LPCTSTR' c:\users\caristid\documents\visual studio
> 2013\projects\ftd2xx\ftd2xx\ftd2xx.cpp    100 1   ftd2xx
>
> IntelliSense: argument of type "PVOID" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCTSTR"   c:\Users\caristid\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ftd2xx\ftd2xx\ftd2xx.cpp    100 35  ftd2xx

I assume that these are general purpose errors and it can be solved by simply using the right variables.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Why would you cast the first argument to void pointer in the first place?

Comment: Your code is wrong. But you have not provided enough information for anyone to suggest a fix. What is the data type of `LocId` ?

Comment: long integer. I declared it as a global parameter, and the FTDI functions should accept it and convert it by themselves

Answer (score 1):

The compiler expects the first parameter to be of type `LPCTSTR` which is a "Long Pointer to a Const TCHAR STRing".
By casting `LocId` to `PVOID` you're passing in a `void*` as first parameter.
If `LocId` is already a string, remove the cast; otherwise find a string to pass to the function.